# linear transformation problems

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, numerical-linear-algebra

i'm having big trouble solving this one, and i just can't understand it.

V is a linear subspace with a finite dimension, and T:V->V is a linear transformation such that $T^3=0$. there's also $v \in V$ such that $T^2(v) \neq 0$.

1)prove that I-T is an isomorphism and find $(I-T)^-1.

2)prove that the group {v,T(v),T^2 (v)} is linear independent and consists of only 3 vectors.

3)prove that if dimV=3 then $kerT \subset ImT$ and there's base B of V so $[T]_B = \begin{matrix}
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{matrix}$

what i tried to do:

1)i tried to find $(I-T)^{-1}$ by using that it's said that $T^3=0$, $I-0=(I-T)(I+T+T^2)$, so $\frac{I}{I-T}=I+T+T^2$. my question is if $\frac{I}{I-T} = (I-T)^{-1}$. if not, then i really don't know how to solve it.

2)since v and $T^2(v)$ are 2 different vectors, they are linear independent. i don't know how to prove that T(v) is linearly independent to v, $T^2(v)$.

3)no idea on how to solve it. i would really like to see a detailed answer to learn how to approach such difficult problems for the next time.

thank you very much, i tried to solve it for 4 hours and still no luck.

Comment: What is $t$ in $t^3 = 0$? Is this a typo?

Comment: Hints: for (2) assume that the vectors are linearly dependent and derive a contradiction using $T^3=0$ and $T^2(v)\ne0$. The second part of (3) is an immediate consequence of (2).

Comment: meant to be $T^3$